# How to make Http get request URL consist of pipelines in swift 3?

Tags: ios, swift, http-get

I have a made a get request from swift 3. That url has pipelines. Without pipeline its working fine but when i add the pipeline the code breaks saying found nil while unwrapping optional value error.

Here is my url 
let url = URL(string:"https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=colombo&destination=kandy&waypoints=optimize:true|&key=AIzaSyCNBcQLIVvNwqjkYiLawnYK_AM")

Here is my code:

```
func synchronusGetRequstForExternalAPI(api_url:String, headers:[ String: String]) -> ResultModel {

        let resultModel = ResultModel()

        //create the url with URL
        let url = URL(string:"https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=colombo&destination=kandy&waypoints=optimize:true|&key=AIzaSyCNBcQLIVvNwqjkYiLawnYK_OK4EQbRM5M")
        //create the URLRequest object using the url object
        var request = URLRequest(url: url!)

        //set headers
        for item in headers {
            request.addValue(item.value, forHTTPHeaderField: item.key)
        }

        let semaphore = DispatchSemaphore(value: 0)
        let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request as URLRequest) {
            (data, response, error) in


            if(error != nil){
                resultModel.ErrorType = .NO_INT
                resultModel.JsonReslut = JSON.null

            }else{

                if let resp = response as? HTTPURLResponse{
                    if(resp.statusCode == 200){
                        if let jsonResult = JSON(data) as? JSON {

                            resultModel.ErrorType = .NO_ERROR
                            resultModel.JsonReslut = jsonResult
                        }
                    }else{
                        if let jsonResult = JSON(data) as? JSON {

                            resultModel.ErrorType = .SEREVR_ERROR
                            resultModel.JsonReslut = jsonResult
                        }else{
                            resultModel.ErrorType = .SEREVR_ERROR
                            resultModel.JsonReslut = JSON.null
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            semaphore.signal()
        }
        task.resume()
        _ = semaphore.wait(timeout: DispatchTime.distantFuture)

        return resultModel
    }
```

Can anyone tell me why is this happening?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`|` is not a character allowed in URL. Try to percent escape the URL string

```
let url = URL(string:"https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=colombo&destination=kandy&waypoints=optimize:true|&key=AIzaSyCNBcQLIVvNwqjkYiLawnYK_OK4EQbRM5M".stringByAddingPercentEncodingWithAllowedCharacters(NSCharacterSet.URLFragmentAllowedCharacterSet()))
```